# Is it possible to install microsoft office 365 and power bi in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, playonlinux, office365

Im Using Ubuntu 18.04. I want to install Microsoft Office 365 and Power BI on my Linux machine without VM. Is it Possible?.

I have checked with Wine and Playonlinux also, MsOffice2013 has been installed but Office365 cannot able to install.

Comment: I think not. See also this: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-use-microsoft-office-linux/

Comment: Thanks FedonKadifeli...